# Problem with including files based on (non-defined) variable

Tags: php

i have a PHP site with the following code in it:

```
<?php
$p = $_GET['p']
include("$p.inc");
?>
```

Whenever I send a visitor to a page like `index.php?p=contact` for example I want the file `contact.inc` to be included. This works fine.

Now I want a certain file to be included (e.g. `start.inc`) when the visitor is sent to `index.php` without any GET variables. However, an error message is returned which tells me that $p is undefined (which it logically is).

I tried fixing this problem by using the isset function like so:

```
<?php
if(!isset($p)) $p = "start";
else $p = $_GET['p'];
include("$p.inc");
?>
```

but this doesn't work because now $p always contains the string "start" and I can't send the visitor to `index.php?p=contact` anymore - it will still include `start.inc`

Can somebody please help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly specify the allowable values​​, obtained from outside.

```
<?php
    $allowed_pages = array(
        'home' => 'home.inc',
        'contact' => 'contact.inc',
    );

    $page = @$_GET['p'];

    $file = array_key_exists($page, $allowed_pages) ? $allowed_pages[$page] : $allowed_pages['home'];

    include($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should white-list your pages anyway, for security. so:

```
<?php
   $p = $_GET['p']
   switch($p){
      case 'contact': 
         include("contact.inc");
         break;
      default:
         include("start.inc");
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your $p variable just like this:

```
$p = array_key_exists('p', $_GET) ? preg_replace('!\W!', '', $_GET['p']) : 'start';
```

Answer (score 1):

you're checking $p instead of $_GET['p'] so, as $p is never set, you always land at starting page.
anyway you have to sanitize this variable first.
good practice would be like this (assuming pages stored in a "pagedata" folder and have .php extension):

```
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
  $p = basename($_GET['p']);
} else {
  $p = "start";
}
$fileName = "pagedata/$p.inc.php";
if(is_readable($fileName)) {
    include($fileName);
} else {
    include("pagedata/404.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer an array-map or a `switch` like Nanne suggested.

At the very least use `basename()` if you want to keep using the $p variable directly in the include statement. And this is how you could avoid the "error" (which is a debug notice, btw):

```
<?php
   $p = @$_GET["p"]   or   $p = "start";

   $p = preg_replace("/\W+/", "", $p);    // minimum filtering
   include("./$p.inc");
?>
```

Comment: would you mind explaining the following piece? `$p = preg_replace("/\W+/", "", $p);`

Comment: Yes. That's a regex filter. It removes any "non-word" characters. Meaning it only leaves in letters, numbers or underscores.

Comment: Ah thanks! I guess this is particularly useful if the variable is manipulated by the visitor? If I am the only person in charge of the code I don't necesarrily need to filter my variables, correct?

Comment: Better safe than sorry. If you were the only one using the website, then yes. But otherwise ***any*** user can manually enter the URL and a fake parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all!

I combined most of your suggestions to the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$pages = array(
'start'=>'Start.inc';
'contact'=>'Contact.inc';
'about'=>'About.inc';
};

$p = array_key_exists(@$_GET['p'], $pages) ? preg_replace('!\W!', '', $_GET['p'] : 'start';
$p = ucfirst($p);

$page = "./$p.inc";
if(is_readable($page)) include($page);
else include(./404.);
?>
```

I particularly like the array-map (as suggested by Alex and mario) for security reasons aswell as the error page idea by Col. Shrapnel.